# Lifecycle of NSTextLayoutFragment

Tags: cocoa, textkit

I'm trying to figure out how all these elements in TextKit 2 work together.

1. `NSTextElement` - Abstract class and meant to be subclassed. macOS provides a concrete subclass NSTextParagraph.
2. `NSTextLayoutManager` - Probably not meant to be subclassed. Accepts a delegate that can provide a `NSTextLayoutFragment` for a given `NSTextElement`.
3. `NSTextContentManager` - Abstract class. Interface allows for concrete instances to provide an array of `NSTextElement` for a given `NSTextRange`.

I'd like to customize the way text is presented, and am having the devils time doing it :-)

I have subclassed `NSTextContentManager` and generate `NSTextElement`s (on the paragraph level). If it's an `NSTextParagraph`, TextKit seems to automagically (?) generate the corresponding `NSTextLineFragment`s when the `NSTextLayoutFragment` is created.

When the `NSTextLayoutFragment` is created it's state will be .none (I think). What makes it move between the different states (.none -> .layoutAvailable)? I don't see any customization points for this. When customizing `NSTextLayoutFragment`, should I just do layout at init (and store it somewhere)? Or is there a better place to do this?

Thanks